# 2.9 render Animation Rendering only some of the animation

Tags: rendering, animation

I've made an animation, but when I go to render out an image sequence or video file all I get is SOME of my animation. So for example one arm is animating and the other is not animating in the render. My viewport animation works just fine though.

Comment: Can you possibly include some screenshots of the undesired behavior?  It's really hard to understand what's going wrong without more details.

Answer (score 0):

Welp. I'm an idiot.... turns out I was loading blender 2.8 and when the file was last saved working in 2.9. My render is working normally now in 2.9